# Python import module from outside directory

Tags: python, import

Hello i'm currently have a real_estate_spider.py(inside spiders folder) script that required to import from items.py which is located outside directory(tutorial)

here is my folder structure

```
\---tutorial
|   items.py
|   middlewares.py
|   pipelines.py
|   settings.py
|   __init__.py
|
+---spiders
|   |   real_estate_spider.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   \---__pycache__
|           real_estate_spider.cpython-36.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
|           不動産.cpython-36.pyc
|
\---__pycache__
        items.cpython-36.pyc
        middlewares.cpython-36.pyc
        pipelines.cpython-36.pyc
        settings.cpython-36.pyc
        __init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

Here is my real_estate_spider.py file which has the import:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import real_estateItem
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

How do i import real_estateItem class which located from items.py in my real_estate_spider.py ?
Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error message when executing your script?

Comment: yes i do i get "File "real_estate_spider.py", line 2, in <module>
 from ..items import real_estateItem
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: Ok, how do you execute the script? Do you run it directly (e.g. `python real_estate_spyder.py`?

Comment: Yes i run directly like that cause i'm gonna use it with docker-compose so it will execute it rightaway

Answer (score 5):

did you try

```
from .. import items
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import items
```

while in real_estate_spider.py

Comment: invalid syntax :<

Comment: still the same error as when i first try" attempted relative import beyond top-level package" :(

Comment: try checking your system path , if you're trying on jupyter network online, you can have these issues,
your checking system path with 
import sys  (then next line)

sys.path

Comment: 4 years later lol, but i think they were trying to write `import <module_name>` directly,  whereas the answer meant to change `<module name>` with `items`

Comment: Yeah <module_name> part should actually be `items`

Answer (score 1):

Try appending the parrent dir to python

**Ex:** *real_estate_spider.py*

```
import sys
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir)))

import scrapy
from items import real_estateItem
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Comment: but im trying to upload this script to docker which will run on other machines, will it affect if i try to docker run on other machines .Where should i put the path file in ? im still new to python and dont know about the sys and os module

Comment: I am not sure if this will cause problem with docker. I don't have one to test it right now..

Comment: im still confused on what to put in on the _file_, dir_patch, os.pardir

Comment: You have to just execute the above snippet as it is.....you do not need to modify anything

Comment: oh ok. it returned with "unable to import 'items'"

Comment: What does this print `print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir)))` ?

Comment: name 'dir_path' is not defined